ADO Pipeline publish npm package to local Artifacts
I've been struggling with getting my npm package to publish correctly to my local ADO Artifact repository using ADO pipelines and a YAML file.  Everything was looking good, until I attempted to use the package in another project, and discovered that only the package.json file was published along with the node_modules folder, not the code that was generated by npm build.
Also, that the code that is being generated for the package is from a subset of the total Storybook project. It's just some theming code as of right now, with the rest of the components being handled later.
Here is my YAML file:
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
  paths:
    include:
      - src/themes
  tags:
    include:
      - patch
    exclude:
      - major
      - minor

resources:
  - repo: self

stages:
  - stage: Publish
    displayName: Publish Theme Package
    jobs:
      - job: Publish
        displayName: Publish to ADO Artifact feed
        pool:
          vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"
        steps:
          - checkout: self
            persistCredentials: true
            clean: true
          - task: npmAuthenticate@0
            inputs:
              workingFile: .npmrc
          - task: NodeTool@0
            displayName: "update node.js to latest version"
            inputs:
              versionSource: "spec"
              versionSpec: "20.x"
              checkLatest: true
          - task: Npm@1
            displayName: "Update npm to latest version"
            inputs:
              command: "custom"
              customCommand: "install -g npm@latest"
          - task: Npm@1
            displayName: npm install
            inputs:
              command: install
          - task: Npm@1
            displayName: npm run build
            inputs:
              command: "custom"
              customCommand: "run build"

          # - task: CopyFiles@2
          #   inputs:
          #     SourceFolder: '/src/themes'
          #     Contents: |
          #       /src/themes/*
          #     TargetFolder: '/src/dist'
          #   displayName: 'Copy theme files'
          
          # - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
          #   inputs:
          #     targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactsStagingDirectory)'
          #     artifact: 'wec-themes'
          #     publishLocation: 'pipeline'
          #   displayName: 'Publish npm artifact'
    
          - bash: | # Grab the package version
               v=`node -p "const p = require('./package.json'); p.version;"`
               echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=packageVersion]$v"
          - task: CmdLine@2 # Push changes to GitHub (substitute your repo)   
            inputs:
              script: |
                git config --global user.email "ADOPipeline@company.com"
                git config --global user.name "Azure Pipeline"
                git add package.json
                git commit -a -m "Automated Commit from Azure DevOps"
                git push -u origin HEAD:master
          - task: Npm@1
            displayName: npm version patch
            inputs:
              command: "custom"
              customCommand: "version patch -force"
          - task: Npm@1
            displayName: npm publish
            inputs:
              command: publish
              publishRegistry: useFeed
              publishFeed: removed
              workingDir: "/dist/"
              verbose: true



I've commented out some of the copy commands, only because I was trying to get it to work.
NPM Build logs from the latest run:
cropped the first 30 lines
> design-portal@1.1.2 build
> tsc && vite build

vite v5.2.12 building for production...
transforming...
✓ 284 modules transformed.
rendering chunks...

[vite:dts] Start generate declaration files...
computing gzip size...
dist/base-theme.js            0.08 kB │ gzip:  0.09 kB
dist/index.js                 0.23 kB │ gzip:  0.14 kB
dist/light/light-theme.js     5.71 kB │ gzip:  1.43 kB
dist/dark/dark-theme.js       8.31 kB │ gzip:  1.57 kB
dist/base-theme-DYM8UH8-.js  95.62 kB │ gzip: 23.51 kB
[vite:dts] Declaration files built in 4305ms.

✓ built in 5.57s

Finishing: npm run build


{
  "name": "design-portal",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.1.2",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
 ...

I still receiving an error on publish. See the log below
Starting: npm publish
==============================================================================
Task         : npm
Description  : Install and publish npm packages, or run an npm command. Supports npmjs.com and authenticated registries like Azure Artifacts.
Version      : 1.242.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm
==============================================================================
##[warning]Can't find loc string for key: Info_GotAndMaskAuth
##[warning]Can't find loc string for key: Info_GotAndMaskAuth
/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/20.15.1/x64/bin/npm --version
10.8.2
##[warning]Can't find loc string for key: Info_GotAndMaskAuth
##[warning]Can't find loc string for key: Info_GotAndMaskAuth
##[warning]Can't find loc string for key: Info_GotAndMaskAuth
##[warning]Can't find loc string for key: Info_GotAndMaskAuth
##[error]Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/dist/*'
Finishing: npm publish

Adding additional details around the @latest


What package files do you expect? Can you confirm it the NPM build has generated the expected files and check if the files are existing in the dist folder?

@KevinLu-MSFT I can confirm that the npm build generated the files.  I'll post the logs.

Please refer to my answer and add the files  field to your package.json file. Then you can custom the included files in the npm package. At the same time, you also need to check if the ignore files exists in your repo. You need to make sure that the dist folder is not excluded in the ignore file.

@KevinLu-MSFT I already had the dist folder in my package.json file. I will post it. I did add a .npmignore file to the repo and removed the dist folder from it, which was copied from the .gitignore, which had it in there.

Do you mean that after adding the files field, it shows the file not found error?

That was happening prior to any changes. The files field in the package.json was already including the dist folder.  I didn't have to make any changes to include it.  The only change I made was to add the .npmignore

Please refer to the update in my answer. You need to change the workingDir in the npm publish task.   You need to set the path to the Folder where the package.json file located. Then it will find the correct package.json file to use. Refer to this doc about npm task settings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/npm-v1?view=azure-pipelines

I have checked the Pipeline log and confirmed that the files are existing in the dist folder.
To include the dist folder in the npm package, you can add the files filed in the package.json file and set the dist folder.
For example:
Package.json
{
  "name": "angular-realworld",
  "version": "0.0.0",  
   .....
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",

  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "^18.13.0 || ^20.9.0"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist/",
    "src/"
  ],
 
  "dependencies": {
...
}

Note: We need to set the dist folder path based on the actual path.
Refer to the doc: files in package.json

The "files" field is an array of files to include in your project. If you name a folder in the array, then it will also include the files inside that folder. (Unless they would be ignored by another rule.)

On the other hand, you can check if the .gitignore or .npmignore files are existing in your repo. If yes, you can check if the dist folder has been excluded in the ignore file.
When you npm publish, if you don't have an .npmignore file, npm will use your .gitignore file.
You can create a .npmignore file based on your .gitignore file, without ignoring the dist folder. Refer to this doc: Keeping files out of your Package
Here is my result:

Update:

##[error]Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/dist/*'

For the latest error in the question, the cause of the issue is that you need to define the package.json file folder path in the npm task instead of the dist folder.
For example:
      - task: Npm@1
        displayName: npm publish
        inputs:
          command: publish
          publishRegistry: useFeed
          publishFeed: removed
          workingDir: "folder path where package.json located"
          verbose: true


So everything appeared to be working fine after my change to the working directory of the publish task, but I got a new error message: npm error code EINVALIDTAGNAME npm error Invalid tag name "@latest" of package "@latest": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes. I'm not explicitly tagging the package

@RobM From the package.json and YAML code, I indeed not see any tags related to @latest. Can you share more details about the error pipeline log? Are you getting the error message when publishing the package or installing the package?

Tt was during the pipeline publish task.  I added a screen shot of the error

@RobM I have checked the screenshot. It is indeed a strange error.  But at least we can see that the dist folder has been included in the npm package. For the new error, you can try to downgrade the node and npm version and check if it can work.

I notice another issue: publish missing "name" field was set to an empty string in the pipeline log. It seems that the name field is missing in the Package.json. Can you try to check it? you can refer to the package.json sample in my answer(e.g. "name": "angular-realworld",).

And from the package.json you shared in the question, you need to remove the field: "private": true, in the package.json when publishing the npm package.

I handled all of that.  I'm downgrading node to from v20 to v18

@RobM No Problem. Please feel free to share the result with us.

That appears to have worked.  I downgraded node.js to v18 and npm to v8.  Checking the consumer project, the node_modules folder for the package, and it has the correct files in place. Testing the consumer project now.

Glad to know that it can work  now!!

I really appreciate the assistance.
